# how to switch the theme of self created react page by click the switch button on the nav bar

Tags: docusaurus

Already Wrap my page with

When switch the button, the color of nav bar changes, but not the page content.

I can change the content theme by importing the following files from ant design;

```
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';  //white mode
//import 'antd/dist/antd.dark.css';   //dark mode
```

so how to import different css file by click on the switch button?

Thanks.

Comment: Already Wrap my page with <Layout>

Answer (score -1):

Create two separate components for **darkMode** and **whiteMode** and use `conditional rendering` with `states` or `context provider` with onClick function.

import **darkMode** styles inside `<DarkModeComponent/>` and **whiteMode** styles in `<WhiteModeComponent/>`.

```
const [darkmode,setDarkmode]=useState(false)
```

and `onClick` function in like below:

```
function onClick(){ setState (s => !s) };
```

and in your components:

```
return ({darkmode ? <DarkModeComponent/> : <WhiteModeComponent/>})
```

Also, you can use `context Provider` for handling this state and pass it to child components.like this : [context.provider for swithing theme](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/dark-mode-for-react-app-using-context-api-and-hooks/)